# LENOVO workstation and UBUNTU

Tags: lenovo

I would like to know if the LENOVO workstation are certified with the UBUNTU distribution version 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Ubuntu Certified Hardware page: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/

Lenovo is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find out is to make a backup with [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [PING](http://ping.windowsdream.com/), and then just try it. If it doesn't work like you want it, roll back safely using the backup.